# How to JPA sub query works with parameters

Tags: java, jpa

I am trying to writing this query. But this query giving me an error while fetching result. Please let me know whats wrong with query.

```
  List<String[]> returnList = new ArrayList<String[]>();
    String nativeQuery = "select EMP_NO, FIRST_NAME, LAST_NAME from isisdba.emplyee e where e.EMP_ACTIVE_IND='A' and e.END_DATE is null and" +
        "e.EMP_NO in (select er.EMP_NO from isisdba.employee_role er where er.ROLE_id in (select r.ROLE_ID from isisdba.roles r where r.ROLE_NAME in (:roles)))";
    Query query = em.createNativeQuery(nativeQuery);
    query.setParameter("roles"

, roles);
```

Thanks in Advance

Comment: add your error code also

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have missed a space in the concatenation of the query

`null and" +
        "e.EMP_NO`

Should be this:

`null and " + /* Here space is needed */
        "e.EMP_NO`

Comment: Thanks. I was understanding, parameter can not be passed in sub queries. Did not see the query syntax. Thanks once again